# Connect to shared folder to create directory on server

Tags: java, server

How to create directory on server to save files?

I try this

```
Path path = Paths.get("177.177.22.22//C://folderToSave" + id);
Files.createDirectories(path);
```

but don't create folder in this server.

When i remove `177.177.22.22//C://` work local.

Any idea?

I need to connect from my computer to this server...

Comment: Try`"\\\\177.177.22.22\\C:\\folderToSave"`

Comment: Java can read network shares simply like that?

Comment: Have you tried: `Path path = Paths.get("//177.177.22.22/C:/folderToSave" + id);` or `Path path = Paths.get("//177.177.22.22/C$/folderToSave" + id);`

Comment: when i put "\\\\177.177.22.22\\C:\\folderToSave" i got Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal character [:] in path

Comment: check the permissions on the folder, and if your java process owner has write permissions in parent folder.. And there's no disk drive assignment in a network share. Just use the UNC path like you'd use in your file explorer.